# Passing parameters as dict to tx.run in Neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-python-driver

I'm trying to write a generic function to take a Cypher query and a dictionary of parameters and be able to dynamically run any given query. What I have looks like this:

```
def _run_cypher(tx, cypher, params = {}):
    results = []
    tx.run(cypher, parameters=params)
```

With queries that look like this:

```
'CREATE INDEX ON :$label(filemd5)'
```

And passing params as

```
params = {'label': label}
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid input '$': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 18 (offset: 17))
"CREATE INDEX ON :$label(filemd5)"
```

Either I am going wrong, or in this context you can't pass a dict of named parameters to tx.run()...can anyone set me straight? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use parameters as label names

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/

You will need to create your own generated query with the desired label and safety checks.

However, you might want to look into the apoc addon, which may allow this.